How would I authenticate a user and pull their data using google calendar api in Android Studios?
After googlesignInOptions being deprecated, I haven't been able to figure out how to get a user's data using google calendar api.
I successfully logged them in using the new Credential Manager but can't find any recent articles or information on how to authenticate and access the data. this is my code:
fun LogIn(navController: NavHostController) {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val onClick: () -> Unit = {
        val googleIdOption: GetGoogleIdOption = GetGoogleIdOption.Builder()
            .setFilterByAuthorizedAccounts(false) // Query all google accounts on the device
            .setServerClientId("CLIENT_ID_HERE")
            .build()

        val request = GetCredentialRequest.Builder()
            .addCredentialOption(googleIdOption)
            .build()

        val credentialManager = CredentialManager.create(context)



fun handleSignIn(result: GetCredentialResponse) {
    // Handle the successfully returned credential.
    val credential = result.credential

    when (credential) {

        is CustomCredential -> {
            if (credential.type == GoogleIdTokenCredential.TYPE_GOOGLE_ID_TOKEN_CREDENTIAL) {
                try {
                    val googleIdTokenCredential = GoogleIdTokenCredential
                        .createFrom(credential.data)
                    val tokenCredential = googleIdTokenCredential.idToken



                    // Send googleIdTokenCredential to your server for validation and authentication
                } catch (e: GoogleIdTokenParsingException) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Received an invalid google id token response", e)
                }
            } else {
                // Catch any unrecognized custom credential type here.
                Log.e(TAG, "Unexpected type of credential")
            }
        }

        else -> {
            // Catch any unrecognized credential type here.
            Log.e(TAG, "Unexpected type of credential")
        }
    }
}



